# Use Firebase Functions and socket.io to create a chat app

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I tried to communicate with Flutter using socket.io in Firebase Functions. However, I am having a hard time with the constant “was not upgraded to websocket” error. please i need help

There is a problem with the connection itself not being established.

Comment: WebSockets and socket.io do not work in Cloud Functions for a variety of reasons discussed in the duplicates. You will need to use a different backend product that doesn't place restrictions on the connections it can maintain.

Comment: Dear. Doug Stevenson -
Your answer was helpful.
thank you.